# cin.get() issue with empty line

Tags: c++, string, line

When I run the following code and insert a new line (press enter) when prompted for
the golf structure, the second call to the function doesn't request input and finishes as if I've pressed enter again.

I've read up on : cin.get() , cin.clear() , cin.ignore(...) but nothing seems to help.

I'm pretty sure that it has nothing to do with multiple .cpp files and the header but I'm putting the code as is.

I'm using Visual Studio C++ 2010 - Express.

Thanks in advance for your help!

header file : golf.h

```
#ifndef GOLF_H
#define GOLF_H

const int Len = 40;

struct golf{

    char fullname[Len];
    int handicap;

};

int setgolf(golf & g );
void showgolf(const golf & g );

#endif
```

golf.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "golf.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int setgolf(golf & g ){

    cout << "Enter a name for the golf structure:" << endl;
    if  (cin.get(g.fullname,Len)) {     
        cin.get(); // deals with the '\n' incase the user inputs a valid string
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }

}
void showgolf(const golf & g ){

    cout << "this golf structure contains the following information:" << endl;
    cout << "name:      " << g.fullname << endl ;
    cout << "handicap:  " << g.handicap << endl ;

}
```

main ()

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "golf.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main()
{

    golf myGolf;

    // check of int setgolf(golf & g );
    int answ = setgolf(myGolf); //try to input empty string
    showgolf(myGolf);
    cout << "the number returned :" << answ << endl ;

    answ = setgolf(myGolf); // normal string
    showgolf(myGolf);
    cout << "the number returned :" << answ << endl ;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might consider the free-function [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) in this effort.

Comment: I think cin.get() does not consume the newline character that is produced when you hit enter. So whenever you call it again, it is consumed there, taking no input. If you want a quick answer, call cin.get() twice to take a single input.

Comment: mostruash -> already tried it a few times. no luck. WhozCraig -> I'm trying to get familiar with cin.get(). *** forgot to initiate myGolf, myGolf = { "some-name" , 6 } ; but that's irrelevant here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem happens when you just press enter in the first prompt. The input stream is marked as eof, an error condition flag (that's why it returns 0). The input stream then stops working.

It seems that you're using a kind of *old* C++, pre ISO 1998, while I don't think you need that. However, if you want to stick with your approach, then do the following: after `cin.getline()` (no need to return anything) write: `cin.clear(); cin.sync();`, as follows:

```
void setGolf(Golf &g)
{
    cout << "Enter a name for the golf structure:" << endl;
    getline( cin, g.fullname ) );

    cin.clear();
    cin.sync();
}
```

Now, about *modernizing* your code. First of all, you can use the standard library's class `string`, which is able to store a string literal, even growing if needed, without giving a maximum value of chars. This is somewhat confusing, since you are including the header `string`, which will include that class, but you're not using it. The use of `string` also comes with other advantages, such as automatically correcting the potential buffer overflow which could happen in your `Golf` structure. So I would change your structure to be:

```
struct Golf{
    string fullname;
    int handicap;
};
```

Now you can use `getline()`, in `utility`, which reads a whole line and stores it in `string`, doing all the magic for you. So you could change your `golf.cpp` file, to:

```
#include <utility>

//...

void setGolf(Golf &g)
{
    cout << "Enter a name for the golf structure:" << endl;
    getline( cin, g.fullname ) );   
}
```

You can now also change the return type to `void`. It is not probable to experience an error of any kind while using `getline()`. Anyway, take into account that you could return `bool` (boolean type), which is a built-in type, with literals `true` and `false`.

I am certain that you could change your `main()` now, to a simpler style:

```
int main()
{

    Golf myGolf;

    setGolf(myGolf);
    showGolf(myGolf);

    setGolf(myGolf);
    showGolf(myGolf);

    return 0;
}
```

Finally, you could consider encapsulating your information in a class, instead of a struct, but that is a whole different issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Baltasarq -> thanks for the great tips! and yes the #include <string> is redandent. unfortunately I really want to understand this specific issue with cin.get(). would you happen to know why the above problem occurs ? I have a fresh install of visual studio 2010, It would strike me as odd if it installs by default with an outdated standart

Comment: This problem happens when you just press enter in the first prompt. The input stream is marked as eof, and error condition flag (that's why it returns 0). The input stream then stops working. If you want to stick with your approach, then do the following: after cin.getline() (no need to return anything) write: cin.clear(); cin.sync();

Comment: Baltasarq -> Thanks ! I've tried cin.get() ; cin.clear() earlier. but cin.sync(); did the trick ! I will read some about it. I will be happy to mark your answer as correct, just post your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also leave `char[]` instead of replacing it with string(I am still learning, so if I'm wrong please correct me). I think that when 
`std::cin.get(char *,Size)` is not able to load characters, it's turning 2 bits on 0, fail and error, this is my solution:

```
std::cin.get(g.fullname, Len);
if(!std::cin)
{
  std::cin.clear();
  std::cin.get();
  std::cout << "You inserted empty line." << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```